# Scala Array with different data types

Tags: arrays, scala, any

*as we know that scala array contains data of the same type. But when I declared array as

```
var a = new Array[Any](3)
```

I am able to store different data types.

```
a(0)=5
a(1)="hello"
a(2)=1.5
```

how is it possible? if it is wrong then what is the option we have in scala to store different data types?*

Comment: I think a proper answer for this is too broad. Please consult one of the many  Scala tutorials

Comment: Your question suggests that you conceive of a value as having only a single, unique type. But it doesn't — in a language with subtyping, a value can be a member of many types at once.

Answer (score 7):

The notion of "same type" always depends on a level of generality. In Scala, the level of generality is determined by formal type.

Are 3 and 7 "of the same type"? If we write...

```
val a : Int = 3
val b : Int = 7
```

then they of of the same type `Int`. But, if we define bit-length restricted `Int` types (which we are very welcome to do in Scala), we might write

```
val a : Int2 = 3
val b : Int3 = 7
```

and they no longer appear to be of the same type!

If we define an inheritance hierarchy

```
trait Animal;
class Dog extends Animal;
class Frog extends Animal;
```

then do `Dog` and `Frog` have the same type? If we write

```
val d : Dog  = new Dog
val f : Frog = new Frog
```

then it looks like the answer is no. But if we write

```
val d : Animal = new Dog
val f : Animal = new Frog
```

then they look like they do have the same type. Consistent with that, if I declare an array like

```
val arr : Array[Dog] = Array.ofDim[Dog](5)
```

then I can't put a frog in it, because a frog is not a dog. But if I declare the a similar array

```
val arr : Array[Animal] = Array.ofDim[Animal](5)
```

Then of course both frogs and dogs can go in it, because at the level of generality of `Animal`, both Frogs and Dogs do have the same type.

In Scala `Any` is a base type from which all other types derive. So, at a very high level of generality, `5`, `"hello"`, and `1.5`, all have the same type `Any`, just as at a high level of generality `Frog` and `Dog` have the same type `Animal`. So there's no problem putting `5`, `"hello"`, and `1.5` into an `Array[Any]`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right about `scala array` and you are indeed storing the data of `same type` here. See this example:

```
scala> val a = Array(5,"hello",1.5)
a: Array[Any] = Array(5, hello, 1.5)
```

We don't see that an array containing an `integer`,`string` and `double` is created. We see that an `array of Any` is created. During `array creation`, the scala compiler looked for the `nearest common supertype in hierarchy` to satisfy the property of Array that it can `hold elements of same type only`. And in this case, `Any` being the supertype of all the classes, satisfies the condition. And, if the compiler can't find the common supertype, Array creation will fail.

Note that, it's not just for Array, same goes for other `collections` that store `same types`.for eg: List

```
scala> val list = List(5,"hello",1.5)
list: List[Any] = List(5, hello, 1.5)
```

**what is the option we have in scala to store different data types?**

As you can see that we are not able to `preserve the type of elements` here in both `List` and `Array`. All the elements are being stored as `Any`. For preserving types of elements and storing them together, scala provides us with `Tuple`:

```
scala> val tuple = (5,"hello",1.5)
tuple: (Int, String, Double) = (5,hello,1.5)
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to support array with different types (unless there is a hierarchy like you have in your example)? This can lead to dirty casting errors

Answer (score 0):

As others have answered why `Array[Any]` can have elements of types String, Boolean, Int etc. let me answer the below part of the question

> if it is wrong then what is the option we have in scala to store
>   different data types?*

The most obvious answer is the [Shapeless library](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless). Shapeless supports an advanced data-structure called `HList` using which you can store heterogenous types in a list without losing the type information.

for example see the below snippet

```
scala> import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import shapeless.{$colon$colon, HList, HNil}

scala> val list = 1 :: "a" :: true :: HNil
list: shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.::[Boolean,shapeless.HNil]]] = 1 :: a :: true :: HNil

scala> list.head
res0: Int = 1 // notice the type of the element is Int and not Any

scala> list.tail.head
res1: String = a

scala> list.tail.tail.head
res2: Boolean = true
```

In the above code you have a val `list` of type `HList` with three elements of types `Int`, `String` and `Boolean`. And when you retrieve the elements of the `HList` the original type of the elements are preserved and you don't get a generic type like `Any` as in the case of Array. This is possible because `HList` stores not just data but the type information of the elements too and properly casts them on retrieval.